# Возможно ли в С++ следующее условие?

Tags: c++

Нужно проверить, находится ли X в определённой области, например от 0 до 1. Можно ли записать это так: 
 `if (0 < x < 1 )`?

Comment: Если нужно именно "проверить, находится ли X в области (0, 1)", то нет, нельзя так записать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, так:

```
if (0 < x && x < 1 )
```

Ваше условие выполняется так:

```
if ((0 < x) < 1 )
```

Проверяется `0 < x`, превращается в 0 или 1 (ложно или истинно, соответственно) и сравнивается с 1. Так что ваше условие будет истинно, если `x <= 0`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98607/discussion-on-answer-by-harry------).